# sympy hyperbolic function integration

Tags: python, sympy

I found a lot of difficult to reach on sympy tools an integral solution that contains an hyperbolic function.
Below the step that stop without solution:
`integrate((sinhx)/(exp(5*x)-1),x)`.
I am a newbye on python/sympy and I imagine that it needs a block of code before to reach the goal.
Could anyone find a solution method?
Thank you to all